# Add Column to Term Database

Tags: php, terms

Currently the Term Database has four columns. `term_id` `name` `slug` `term_group`. I would like to add another column called `menu_order`.

How can i do this?

The outcome i want is to be able to order my custom terms.

If anyone knows of a beter way to do this please let me know. So far i already have code that sets up the input box. I just need help trying to order it using the `get_terms()` function.

```
add_action ( 'section_edit_form_fields', 'create_section_menu_order');
function create_section_menu_order( $tag ) 
{
    //check for existing featured ID
    $section_order = get_option( 'section_menu_order' );
    $order_id = '';
    if ( is_array( $section_order ) && array_key_exists( $tag->term_id, $section_order ) ) {
        $order_id = $section_order[$tag->term_id];
    }
    ?>
        <tr class="form-field">
            <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="section_menu_order"><?php _e('Order') ?></label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="section_menu_order" id="section_menu_order" size="10" style="width:60px;" maxlength="6" value="<?php echo $order_id; ?>"><br />
                <span class="description">The order your Sections will show. (Numeric digits only)</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php
}

add_action ( 'edited_section', 'save_section_menu_order');
function save_section_menu_order( $term_id ) 
{
    if ( isset( $_POST['section_menu_order'] ) && is_numeric($term_id)) 
    {
        $section_menu_order = get_option( 'section_menu_order' ); //load existing category featured option
        $section_menu_order[$term_id] = intval( $_POST['section_menu_order'] ); //set featured post ID to proper category ID in options array   
        update_option( 'section_menu_order', $section_menu_order ); //save the option array
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a feeling that modifying that table is not a good idea.

I hadn't done something like this, but if I needed to deal with considerable amount of meta information for terms I'd try to leverage [Metadata API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Metadata_API), which for terms would involve [setting up separate storage table](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_metadata#Add_Metadata_to_a_Term).